# Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket

Tags: linux, docker

This error persist even when my user is already in the docker group.

I added my user like this:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

Comment: Did you log out and log back in?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48569858/596285

Comment: I am having same issue on Linux MInt 19.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

And then this

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

And then this

```
$ newgrp docker
```

If you are still having the issue, just restart your computer, especially when you are using zsh.